# Sequelize 'upsert' doesn't function as it should be

Tags: orm, sequelize.js, upsert

#### A little background

Well, I was trying to use `upsert` command, however I keep getting errors, and I had no idea what went wrong, I already input the `object` that I want `upsert` (that is `NewIssue`) which is a value based on other call.

**What it does**
Error :(

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "fatal": false,
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO `ms_issue` VALUES () ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ;"
    },
    "original": {
        "fatal": false,
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO `ms_issue` VALUES () ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ;"
    },
    "sql": "INSERT INTO `ms_issue` VALUES () ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ;"
}
```

#### My code

Data Schema:

```
const Issue = sequelize.define('ms_issue', {
    id_Issue: {
        type: Sequelize.NUMBER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    id_IssueTag: {
        type: Sequelize.NUMBER,
    },
    datetime_Issued: {
        type: Sequelize.NOW
    },
    subject_Issue: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    desc_Issue: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    status_Issue: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
}, { timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true });
```

```
app.put('/issues/:id', (req, res) => {
  const id_Staff = req.body.id_Staff
  if (typeof id_Staff !== 'undefined' && typeof id_Staff === 'number') {
    const id_Issue = parseInt(req.params.id)
    if (typeof id_Issue !== 'undefined' && typeof id_Issue === 'number') {
      Issue.findByPk(id_Issue)
        .then(issue => {
          if (issue) {
            const newIssue = {
              subject_Issue: req.body.subject || undefined,
              desc_Issue: req.body.description || undefined,
              id_IssueTag: req.body.tag || undefined
            }
            for (const obj in newIssue) {
              if (typeof newIssue[obj] !== 'undefined') {
                issue[obj] = newIssue[obj]
              }
            }
            const NewIssue = issue
            return NewIssue
          } else res.status(404).send("Issue not found")
        })
        .then(NewIssue => {
          return Issue.upsert(NewIssue)
            .then(bool => {
              if (bool === true) {
                res.status(200).send("Issue has been updated")
                res.status(200).send(NewIssue)
              }
            })
            .catch(err => {
              res.status(500).send(err)
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          res.status(500).send("Cannot connect to database")
        })
    } else {
      res.status(400).send("Invalid parameters: require 'id_Issue'")
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("Unauthorized access")
  }
})
```

**What I wanted**
Able to insert/update on request in `MariaDB`. *And explanation :)*

Answer (score 0):

The generated SQL is invalid - there are no values:

```
"sql": "INSERT INTO `ms_issue` VALUES () ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ;"
```

The SQL should be valid if you specify, roughly as below:

```
...
Issue.upsert({
    id_Issue:  id_Issue,
    subject_Issue: NewIssue.subject_Issue, 
    id_IssueTag : NewIssue.id_IssueTag,
...
```